# Child EventListener not removing before finish/back press

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a child `eventListener` class. this is called by a few different activities. but for some reason when i leave one activity and go to the next. my `listView` keeps hold of the previous data from the listener and also adds the new.

I have tried to add a `removeListener` to the on back press of my activity but the result is still the same.

this is my Listener Class

```
public class aimeEnentListener {
private ListView mlv;
private static ArrayList<String> AppNameList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> ApkList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> Aboutapp = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> appImage = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> Downloadscount = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> DOWNLOADS = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;
private dataListAdapter apkData;
public static String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private static String apkNames;
private Firebase mrootRef;
private  String appname;
private String Apptype;
private String counter,url,apkname,about,appimg,tagname;

private com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener eventListener;
String tag;
public aimeEnentListener (ListView mlv,Context context,String AppType,Firebase mrootRef){
this.mContext = context;
this.mlv = mlv;
this.Apptype = AppType;
this.mrootRef = mrootRef;

}

public void setList() {

 eventListener = new com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        appname = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        counter = dataSnapshot.child("downloads").getValue(String.class);
        url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
        apkname = dataSnapshot.child("apk").getValue(String.class);
        about = dataSnapshot.child("about").getValue(String.class);
        appimg = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
       tagname = dataSnapshot.child("tag").getValue(String.class);


        DOWNLOADS.add(tagname);
        Downloadscount.add(counter);
        AppNameList.add(appname);


        urlList.add(url);
        ApkList.add(apkname);
        Aboutapp.add(about);
        appImage.add(appimg);

        final String[] arr = AppNameList.toArray(new String[AppNameList.size()]);
        String[] arr1 = Aboutapp.toArray(new String[Aboutapp.size()]);
        String[] arr2 = appImage.toArray(new String[appImage.size()]);
        final String[] arr3 = Downloadscount.toArray(new String[Downloadscount.size()]);

        apkData = new dataListAdapter(mContext, arr, arr1, arr2, arr3, mrootRef, Apptype);


        mlv.setAdapter(apkData);
        apkData.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                final Firebase ref = mrootRef.getRef();


                tag = DOWNLOADS.get(i).toString();
                apkNames = AppNameList.get(i).toString();


                DownloadFileFromURL dl = new DownloadFileFromURL(mContext, apkNames, mCurrentPhotoPath);
                dl.execute(urlList.get(i));
                Count_System count = new Count_System(ref);
                count.count();

                App_DownLoadCounter(tag);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            counter = dataSnapshot.child("downloads").getValue(String.class);
            appname = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            counter = dataSnapshot.child("downloads").getValue(String.class);
            url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
            apkname = dataSnapshot.child("apk").getValue(String.class);
            about = dataSnapshot.child("about").getValue(String.class);
            appimg = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
            tagname = dataSnapshot.child("tag").getValue(String.class);
            apkData.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
};



mrootRef.child(Apptype).addChildEventListener(eventListener);

 }

public void App_DownLoadCounter(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
    Firebase ref = mrootRef.getRef();

    ref.child(Apptype).child(tag).child("downloads").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

            if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                mutableData.setValue(0);
            } else {
                int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                mutableData.setValue(count + 1);
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean b, com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
    });
}
public void removeListener(){
    mrootRef.child(Apptype).removeEventListener(eventListener);
}
}
```

then i call it from each activity using

```
 mlv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCastingapps);
    listener = new aimeEnentListener(mlv, Casting_Apps.this, Apptype, mrootRef);
   listener.setList();
```

I have even tried adding the `removeListener` to `onBackpress`

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    finish();
    listener.removeListener();
}
```

Edit****

if i make an exact copy of the listener class and use that on one then use the above listener on the next it works correctly. but i really only wan to use one listener

Comment: You're using a quite old version of the Firebase SDK. If this is a recent project, I recommend switching to the [latest SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: For the concrete problem: is `finish()` already navigating to the other activity? In that case, are you sure `listener.removeListener()` still gets called? It might be worth setting a breakpoint, or adding a `Log.i` to verify that it gets called.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i always seam to have problems updating the sdk. causing loads of errors in my app lol.

Comment: what do u mean by break point @FrankvanPuffelen? also ive added a Log.i how do i find the data

Comment: Please Google for those problems, as neither of them is related to Firebase and they've probably been covered better than I can do here. E.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=android+studio+set+breakpoint and https://www.google.com/search?q=android+studio+find+logcat+output